# Binding to TreeView SelectedItem works as ItemsSource but not for custom DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a TreeView with an ICollection<...> for its ItemsSource. Now I'm trying to use the SelectedItem in some other controls. For some reason, I can properly set a Binding using ElementName for a ListView, but when I try to implement the same for a custom DependencyProperty it never gets updated.

Here's the XAML (ListView works and MyControl doesn't):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.Children}" />
<modules:MyControl Grid.Row="1" Blubbi="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

And the DependencyProperty of MyControl:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BlubbiProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Blubbi), typeof(object), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

public object Blubbi
{
    get => (object) GetValue(BlubbiProperty);
    set => SetValue(BlubbiProperty, value);
}
```

I suspect that something about the DependencyProperty's implementation is wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything technically wrong with your dependency property, but it also does not look particularly useful the way it is implemented. Usually when implementing a dependency property, you want something to happen when it receives a new value. The most basic way to do this is with a value changed callback. For example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BlubbiProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Blubbi), typeof(object), typeof(MyControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(object), (d, e) => ((MyControl)d).OnBlubbiChanged(e.oldValue, e,newValue)));

private void OnBlubbiChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

You can do more advanced things in response to new incoming values  also, but usually don't need to. If you want to read more, here is an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation).

Now all of that is fine for any `DependencyObject`, but if you are an element that extends from `FrameworkElement`, which most elements do, then you can use [FrameworkPropertyMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata) in place of `PropertyMetadata` which provides some additional convenience features in the form of [FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions).

So let's say you use this property in your element's `OnRender` override, then you can ensure render gets automatically invalidated whenever the property value changes so that `OnRender` will be called again.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BlubbiProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Blubbi), typeof(object), typeof(MyControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

Furthermore, if your element is a `Control` that uses a XAML-defined template to represent itself, then you can keep your dependency property as it is and use it in your control template via a `TemplateBinding`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type myNamespace:MyControl}">
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Blubbi}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

So when you say your property never gets updated, I have to ask how do you know that? The code you provided is incomplete, but it does not appear you are actually doing anything with the property that would make it obvious that it changed.

As an additional note, because this often surprises people, the property you have defined to wrap your dependency property will never be invoked via a binding. Bindings use the dependency object system to directly update the dependency property. Although a wrapper property is required in order to be able to set the property from XAML, it is not actually invoked when dealing with a dependency property. In other words, a breakpoint in your wrapper property's setter will never hit. So, never put any important logic in the wrapper property.

---

Edit: If you are still struggling to figure out what is going wrong, you can get the binding to print debug information to your debugger's output window by setting the `TraceLevel` attached property on it to `High` it like this:

```
<modules:MyControl
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Blubbi="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually had no idea that breakpoints in the setter don't hit. However, I also don't reach breakpoints for Blubbi in the override of OnPropertyChanged  or a custom PropertyChangedCallback of the DependencyProperty when I know that the SelectedItem is changing.

Comment: I added some more information to this answer about how you can try to debug the binding to see what it is doing.